# Remove iTunes and Mac App store results when looking for a word

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore, macos, dictionary, look-up

I would like to know whether it is possible to remove the *Itunes Store* and *Mac App Store* results from the word look-up functionality in El Capitan 10.11.1, illustrated below:

[image: iTunes Store]

and App Store:

[image: App Store]

I find the attached look-up results pointless and irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18794?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US), you can disable some "Search results" from *Spotlight* or *Look up*. You can also uncheck the option "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Spotlight Look up", to prevent Look up to work as Spotlight does.

[This link](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22669?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) can also be useful (it refers to Yosemite but the same functionalities are available for El Capitan too).